# Convert ascii code to hexadecimal in UNIX shell script

Tags: shell, bash

I'd like to convert ASCII code (like `-` or `_` or `.`, etc.) to hexadecimal representation in the Unix shell (without `bc` command), eg : `-` => `%2d`.

Any ideas?

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585765/convert-ascii-code-to-hexadecimal-in-unix-shell-script/3587553#3587553) to this question which you cross-posted on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 15):

There's a `printf` tool that simulates the C function; normally it's at `/usr/bin/printf`, but a lot of shells implement built-ins for it as well. You can use `%02x` to get the hex representation of a character, but you need to make sure you pass a string that includes the character in single-quotes (**Edit**: It turns out just a single-quote at the beginning is sufficient):

```
printf "%%%02x\n" "'-"   # Outputs %2d
```

You can make a shell function for convenience:

```
function hex() {
    printf "%%%02x\n" "'$1"
}

hex -   # Outputs %2d
hex _   # Outputs %5f
hex .   # Outputs %2e
```

Comment: The only issue with this is with 2-byte characters whose code starts with 0. eg `hex 'ץ'` will give `%5e5` rather than `%05e5`. You should change the body of the function to `s=`printf "%%%04x" "'$1"`; echo "%${s%00}"`

Answer (score 6):

[`xxd`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/xxd.man) is a hex-dump utility shipped as part of the `vim-common` package
It has a handy `-p` option which outputs a continuous 'plain/postscript' hexdump style.. This can easily be reversed via `-r`... `-u` will output upper-case Hex-Digits.

```
$ echo -n "M" |xxd -p    # 1 ASCII char= 1 UTF-8 byte; Unicode Codepoint: U+0041
4d

$ echo -n "〶" |xxd -p -u # 1 CJK char= 3 UTF-8 bytes; Unicode Codepoint: U+3036  
E380B6

$ echo -n "Dump a string" |xxd -p -u  
44756D70206120737472696E67

$ echo -n "Dump and Revert" |xxd -p |xxd -r  
Dump and Revert
```

Comment: Perhaps add -p switch when reverting: `xxd -r -p`. Just `xxd -r` didn't work for me in the example above.

Answer (score 5):

Try [od](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/od-invocation.html#od-invocation):

```
$ echo -n "-_." | od -A n -t x1
2d 5f 2e
```

`-A n` means do not print offsets and `-t x1` means format output as 1 byte hexadecimal integer.

Comment: Nice. You can use `echo -n` to omit the newline at the end so `od` doesn't pick it up and turn it into `0a`